# Linux regex error: "unmatched slash and curly braces"

Tags: regex, linux

I have some strings, and among them are:

```
103120!WIFF SOFTBALL BAT I  !25 !20 !01-JUN-90
103121!WIFF SOFTBALL BAT II !30 !24 !01-JUN-90
```

I need to write a regex for `grep` which displays strings with 'bat' and end with 90.

```
grep ‘^.*BAT((.*!)\{\1}))\{\3}90$'
```

The error appears: `unmatched \{`.
I've tested which one of paranthesis isn't fine, but it didn't get any result.

Comment: You mean `grep 'BAT.*90$' file`?

Comment: Yes, that works as I need. Thanks a lot, it's pretty hard to get used to regex expressions for a newbee.

Comment: I don’t understand the error message but you have two unescaped right braces (`}`) and no corresponding unescaped left braces, which makes the regex invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to the unescaped `}`. You have tried to use an interval quantifier in a POSIX BRE pattern, but you have not escaped both the `{` and `}`.

However, it seems you may just use

```
grep 'BAT.*90$' file
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/bcBNfy)

The `BAT.*90$` POSIX BRE pattern here matches

- `BAT` - a `BAT` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `90$` - `90` at the end of the string (line here as `grep` operates on a line by line basis by default)

As no `-o` option was used, `grep` will output the whole lines that contain this pattern, no need for the `^.*` part.